Plaid Link Loading Time
I'm setting up a Plaid integration in Javascript, where the user can consent to sharing their financial records. I'm able to get a plaid link token and to initialize the plaid interface using the link token. However, after the user completes the process and connects their accounts from a bank, it takes up to 4 minutes of loading before triggering the OnSuccess action.
Was hoping someone with experience using Plaid can tell me if that's normal or what the issue could be.

Not typical. I’d suggest contacting Plaid support.
